# Why am I missing required positional arguments when passing a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, scipy, scipy-optimize

I am trying to minimize an error function with Scipy's fmin function. When attempting to pass the function into fmin, iIget an error saying that I am missing positional arguments. Here is the function, taking in arguments m and b:

```
def gumbelError(m, b):
    # define the gumbel function at the points of sorted mm
    gumbel = np.exp(-np.exp(-np.divide(sortedmm - m, b)))
    errors = gumbel - summed
    return np.sum(np.power(errors, 2))

op.fmin(gumbelError, np.array(MLEmean, MLEsd))
```

This returns an error implying that I was trying to evaluate the function rather than passing it, and I don't know what is going wrong:

```
TypeError: gumbelError() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

Comment: Hard to say; `op.fmin` is calling `gumbelError`, so what does *it* pass as arguments?

Comment: op.fmin requires only a callable function and an initial guess.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `fmin` is only going to call `gumbelError` with one argument, unless you provide an additional argument to `fmin` itself.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.8.0/html-scipyorg/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html

Answer (score 0):

fmin can only manage functions with a single input. The problem here was that gumbelError took two inputs. This was solved by modifying gumbelError such that it took a single tuple input, which was then split within the function for use.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).